# Как получить аватарку определенного пользователя vk на php?

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Вообщем есть у меня блог на php, но в апи вконтакте я теряюсь, поэтому спрашиваю тут.
Как мне вывести свою личную аватарку и статус из вконтакте в свой блог? Чтобы при изменении их во вконтакте они менялись и на блоге. Думаю многим блоггерам интересно как это сделать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Создайте приложение iframe
- Скачайте **[APIServerPHPClass.zip](https://vk.com/source/APIServerPHPClass.zip)**
- Там есть файл **vkapi.class.php**, добавьте этот файл в ваш сайт.
- Далее получаем свои данные профиля ВК:

  ```
      require 'vk/vkapi.class.php'; #путь к файлу vkapi.class.php
      $api_id = '0000'; #id приложения
      $secret_key = 'secret'; #секретный ключь приложения
      $user_id = '1'; #Ваш ID ВКонтакте
      //включаю библиотеку VK
      $VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key);
      $prof = $VK->api('getProfiles', array('uids' => $user_id, 'fields' =>'first_name,last_name,photo_100,status,screen_name'));
      $adsd = sizeOf($prof['response']);
              for ($d = 0; $d < $adsd; $d++) {
      echo '<ul id="id__user__profile">
  <li>
      <img src="' . $prof['response'][$d]['photo_100'] . '">
      <a href="http://vk.com/' . $prof['response'][$d]['screen_name'] . '" class="user-name">' . $prof['response'][$d]['first_name'] . ' ' . $prof['response'][$d]['last_name'] . '</a>
      <span class="user-group">' . $prof['response'][$d]['status'] . '</span>
  </li> </ul>';}
  ```

CSS (Стиль мини-профиля): [profile.css](http://bit.ly/18KNadf)

Пример: http://bit.ly/10OHg9e

Comment: а как вы запихнули все это так красиво в html? поделитесь кодом вывода если не желко, php я имею ввиду

Comment: @ochumelec, какой у Вас движок блога?  используете CMS? (WordPress, Joomla и т.д.) чтобы установить мой код, Вы хотя бы должны уметь заливать файлы в файловый менеджер Вашего сайта, где необходима поддержка PHP.

Comment: у меня anchorcms, я начинающий совсем программист, и понимаю как что и куда вставить, только вот код как написать правильно сам с нуля не знаю

Comment: @ochumelec, я изменил код выше (свой), и добавил ссылку на CSS стили для блока, скопируйте со страницы http://vk.cc/1vLNWj весь код, и вставьте (добавьте) в CSS файл Вашего сайта. А PHP код, вставьте туда, где должен быть блок с Вашими данными ВК, и не забудьте изменить uids на свой id VK.

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Comment: извините ещё раз, а можно как-то внести эти поля в переменные типа $photo, $status итд, чтобы потом где угодно их использовать на странице?

Comment: @ochumelec, можно. так: 
   $status = $prof['response'][$d]['status'];
А так, мой код написан для получения нескольких пользователей, например: http://bit.ly/105lDjR  - для будущего :)

Answer (score 10):

Никакой авторизации не надо. Используем метод [`users.get`](http://vk.com/dev/users.get).
Подробнее о полях: [Описание полей параметра fields](http://vk.com/dev/fields)

Пример ссылки: `http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=ID_OR_NICK&fields=photo_200,status`

В ответ придёт `json` такого вида:

```
{
    "response": [{
        "uid": UID,
        "first_name": "Имя",
        "last_name": "Фамилия",
        "photo_200": "URL фотографии",
        "status": "Статус"
    }]
}
```

Пример получения на PHP:

```
$request = 'http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=ID&fields=photo_200,status';
$response = file_get_contents($request);
$info = array_shift(json_decode($response)->response);

var_dump($info->photo_200); // URL фотографии
var_dump($info->status);    // Статус
```

Пример получения на JS с jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?uids=ID&fields=photo_200,status&callback=?', function(resp){
    console.log(resp.response[0].photo_200);
    console.log(resp.response[0].status);
});
```

Comment: а как его также красиво вывести на странице потом?
как вот тут http://vk.cc/1vKFme

Comment: @ochumelec, куда и как выводить - полностью в ваших руках

Comment: да это понятно, только вот как распарсить этот json? я в js нибумбум

Comment: @ochumelec, не обратил внимание на язык. Добавил JS.

Comment: и как этот js теперь заставить записаться в html? простите что достаю глупыми вопросами, я блогер а не программист

Comment: @ochumelec, тут уж лучше почитайте основы - много времени не надо, зато кругозор расширите.

Answer (score 1):

Со статусом все просто. Ссылка для запроса будет такая:
https://api.vk.com/method/status.get?uid=#ID#&access_token=#TOKEN#
Где #ID# - id пользователя, #TOKEN# - ключ доступа, в результате прохождения процесса авторизации.
Вот код в котором можно получить статус:

```
$status_get = "https://api.vk.com/method/status.get?uid=#ID#&access_token=#TOKEN#";
$statusResponce = file_get_contents($status_get);
```

Немного preg_match и текст статуса ваш.
Важно! Для вызова этого метода приложение должно иметь права: activity.
С фотками аналогично но там даже и токен не нужен.

Comment: а как получить токен?и на сколько его хватит? мне ведь просто нужно выводить свою аватарку и статус в блоге, и чтобы они менялись когда я их меняю в вк. 
Никаких приложений мне не нужно.

Comment: Приложение нужно создавать по-любому.
Просто создать Standalone-приложение. О него вам только потребуется id. Дальше пройти авторизацию по ссылке:
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=#APP_ID#&scope=photos,status,offline&redirect_uri=blank.html&display=page&response_type=token 

где #APP_ID# - id Standalone-приложения.
в адресной строке будет токен